# how to define the types of a part of the properties of an object literal?

Tags: typescript, antd

here I have the following code

```
const selectOptions = {
  mode: isTag ? 'tags' : 'combobox',
  ... //other stuff
}

return (<Select {...selectOptions}>...</Select>);
```

The `mode` is inferred as string by TypeScript but `Select` only takes `type ModeOption = "default" | "multiple" | "tags" | "combobox"` so there's an error.

My current way is by doing `mode: (isTag ? 'tags' : 'combobox') as ModeOption`. But I want to avoid using as, is there a better method? How to define the type of only several properties of an object literal?

Comment: Do you have access to the type of Select's props? Then you could do e.g. `const selectOptions: SelectProps = { ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the general case of when you want to avoid automatic type widening, you can use `as const`:

```
const selectOptions = {
  mode: (isTag ? 'tags' as const : 'combobox' as const),
}
```

Unlike other uses of `as` which indicate that you're asserting a type based on *extra* information not available to the compiler, `as const` is not potentially type-unsafe - all it does is tell TS not to widen the type, so don't be afraid to use it.

Comment: Thank you! But is there a general way to define only one property of an object literal and let ts infer the rest?

Comment: Using `as const` on only the `mode` property will work. If you have an additional property `foo: 5`, TS will infer the `foo` property to be a `number`